# Workaround for declaring array in an if condition

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, split, declaration

I have a problem with this part of the code where I want to be able to declare an array and the size of which should be the corresponding no of splits in the string. 
Or do I need to count the no of commas in the string and allocate size accordingly or is there a better solution.

```
    String MapPath2[];
    if(type.equals("comparative"))
        MapPath2[]=args[1].split(",");
```

I haven't had a chance to code in java in the recent past. Please spare me if it is a silly question and guide me as a noob. Appreciate your help.

Comment: That is not valid Java.

Comment: Other than removing the `[]` in the assignment, this should be fine. `String.split` will return the array - you don't need to pre-allocate it.

Comment: Don't name a variable like this. Call it `mapPath2`.

Comment: I know . So I need a workaround for this if possible which can be better than counting the no of commas. Thanks Tichodroma

Comment: Do you mean like this Jon skeet                                String mappath2;
    if(type.equals("comparative"))
        mappath2=args[1].split(",");

Comment: @RED: Something like that, yes - but with the `[]` at the variable *declaration* which were probably in your comment but can't be seen. Did you try that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to declare the size, what you have is fine if you remove the extra `[]`:

```
String MapPath2[];
if(type.equals("comparative"))
    MapPath2=args[1].split(",");
```

The array `split` gives back to you has the appropriate size. If you need to know the resulting size, use `MapPath2.length` (after assigning it).

You'd probably want to do something in the `else` as well, so that `MapPath2` has a definite value either way:

```
String MapPath2[];
if(type.equals("comparative"))
    MapPath2=args[1].split(",");
else
    MapPath2=null;
```

or more concisely:

```
String MapPath2[];
MapPath2 = type.equals("comparative") ? args[1].split(",") : null;
```

(Instead of the `null`s there, **if** having an empty array is preferred for subsequent logic as is sometimes handy, replace `null` with `new String[0]` above and below. Other times, it's more handy to have the `null` as a "no data" flag.)

---

Side note: There are some **overwhelmingly** common code style conventions in the Java world that you would be best advised to use in your code:

1. Variable names should start with a lower case letter, so as not to be confused with class names.
2. The `[]` should go with the type name rather than the variable name.
3. Always use `{}` even when the body of an `if` or `else` is only one line.
4. Put spaces around operators and keywords for ease of reading.

Applying those:

```
String[] mapPath2;
if (type.equals("comparative")) {
    mapPath2 = args[1].split(",");
}
else {
    mapPath2 = null;
}
```

*Many* people also put the `else` on the same line as the `}`, so:

```
String[] mapPath2;
if (type.equals("comparative")) {
    mapPath2 = args[1].split(",");
} else {
    mapPath2 = null;
}
```

Or again, more concisely:

```
String[] mapPath2;
mapPath2 = type.equals("comparative") ? args[1].split(",") : null;
```

Comment: And ideally use more conventional names and square bracket placements :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Indeed. :-) I've added a note at the end about that.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder . I m unable to accept your answer for another 9 minutes more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List` instead of `Array` if you don't know what size it needs be.

Then you can use

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if(type.equals("comparative")){
       Collections.addAll(list, args[1].split(","));
    }
```

Comment: *"You can use `List` instead of `Array` if you don't know what size it needs be."* You *can*, but you can use an array even if you don't know the size, because `split` will handle that for you. In the above, you're still creating an array (in fact, you're creating two, one of them temporary -- and quite possibly creating three or even more as the first may need at least one reallocation during `addAll`, and possibly more than one).